# ProGuard can't find superclass or interface

Tags: java, class, webview

I have work jar. programm, but when I use ProGuard I have next warning

```html
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib\rt.jar]
Warning: Browser: can't find superclass or interface       javafx.scene.layout.Region
Warning: Browser$1: can't find superclass or interface javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener
Warning: Browser$1$1: can't find superclass or interface javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Region
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.layout.Region
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebView
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebView
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebView
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebEngine
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebEngine
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.web.WebEngine
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced method 'javafx.collections.ObservableList getChildren()' in program class Browser
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.collections.ObservableList
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.collections.ObservableList
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced method 'double getWidth()' in program class Browser
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced method 'double getHeight()' in program class Browser
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.HPos
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.HPos
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.VPos
Warning: Browser: can't find referenced class javafx.geometry.VPos
```

and other, 64 warning massage, and my program have some problem. How I can off processing some class at  Pro Guard ? What I should press or write specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need this line in your proguard file to include javafx runtime:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```

Comment: please explain that